# How to optimaly tune my JVM settings of my DSE spark nodes?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, jvm, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have a 6 node cluster with 32 core CPU and 64 GB RAM.

As of now, all are running with default JVM settings of Cassandra (v2.1.5). With this setting, each node uses 40GB RAM and 20% CPU. It is a read heavy cluster with a constant flow of data and deletes.

Do I need to tune the JVM settings of Cassandra to utilize more memory? What other things should I be looking at to make appropriate settings?

Comment: I assume using Azul is not an option ;)

Comment: Why Azul? What would be the benefits?

Comment: Cassandra one of the most biggest users of Azul.  It supports larger heaps with smaller pauses http://www.azulsystems.com/partners/apache-cassandra

Comment: Thanks. Do you think this is already necessary with my cluster size and will help?

Comment: No, but it is an option and it might be the simplest solution in this case.

Comment: "Do I need to" - *you* should know whether the application performs according to your requirements.

Comment: there's my favorite [tuning guide](https://tobert.github.io/pages/als-cassandra-21-tuning-guide.html)